# Show User That Are On A Given Route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a system, and I have a routes like `/document/123`.

In my application I have many users that will eventually edit those documents, and I don't want one user to edit the same document of another. It would be good to give feedback like "Hey, user x is editing this document already".

How can I achieve this in Rails?

I think `ActionCable` would be the answer but I'm still lost. It would be good to have some material or similar code so I can move on with this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the document giving a user exclusive lease to update it. When another user tries to update it, he gets an error message informing him that the document cannot be leased. When lease expires or the first user saves, the document can be edited again.

Example/pseudocode (not tested, be aware - not thread safe):

```
class Document
  def lease!(user: time: 15.minutes)
    fail DocumentLeased if leased? && !leased_to?(user)
    update(leased_to: user, leased_until: Time.now + time)
  end

  def leased_to?(user)
    leased_to == user
  end

  def leased?
    leased_until > Time.now
  end

  def clear_lease
    update(leased_to: nil, leased_until: nil)
  end
end

class DocumentController
 def edit
   # ...
   @document.lease_to(current_user)
 end

 def update
   #...
   @document.clear_lease
 end
end
```

Comment: I would rather like to have a live approach. like google docs, informing that someone is already there.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the answer is Action Cable, if you want to inform the user who is editing and when he will release the document.

There are a lot of resources available, but you an start by checking these:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html
- https://medium.com/rubyinside/action-cable-hello-world-with-rails-5-1-efc475b0208b
- https://www.learnenough.com/action-cable-tutorial

**But,** if you just want to inform the user that this document is edited by other user , you can use a lock/unlock mechanism. The basics is described by @mrzasa in his answer or [here](https://gist.github.com/Stex/6222440).

You just need to inform the user, on `edit` action, that document is locked. The document will be unlocked on `update` only if the current_user is the user who locked the document.